# Ubuntu. (blockchain of version 0.9.3 compatible with 0.10.1?)

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, ubuntu

I have version 0.9.3 of bitcoind on my Ubuntu server and I want to upgrade to 0.10.1,
I have nothing in my wallet.
Does the blockchain 0.9.3 compatible with 0.10.1?
Do I have anything to keep from version 0.9.3 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the official release announcement here:
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1039713.msg11211433#msg11211433

---

### Downgrade warning

Because release 0.10.0 and later makes use of headers-first synchronization and
parallel block download (see further), the block files and databases are not
backwards-compatible with pre-0.10 versions of Bitcoin Core or other software*

---

So upgrading works fine, but if you later decide to downgrade the block and database files won't be compatible.

Answer (score 1):

It should be forward compatible, but making backups of your wallet is always recommended.

Once you upgrade to 0.10.x, downgrading to 0.9.x afterwards may not be possible anymore.

Comment: Forward compatible, not backward compatible. You can upgrade from 0.9 to 0.10, but not the other way around.